# How to use L2 pooling in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement one CNN architecture that uses L2 pooling. The reference paper particularly argues that L2 pooling was better than max pooling, so I would like to try L2 pooling after the activation function.

However, Tensorflow seems to provide only `tf.nn.avg_pool` / `tf.nn.max_pooling` / `tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax`.

Is there a way to implement L2 pooling in Tensorflow?

```
conv = tf.....
h = tf.nn.tanh(conv)
p = tf.pow(tf.nn.ave_pool(tf.pow(h,2)), 0.5)
```

Will this be equivalent? Will this work well in terms of backpropagation?

Comment: maybe something like tf.sqrt(tf.nn.ave_pool(tf.square(h))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who may wonder, when I tried as in Yaroslav Bulatov's response, I could see better performance:

```
tf.sqrt(tf.nn.ave_pool(tf.square(h))
```

Comment: FYI I edited to give the *code*. Comments can disappear.