# How to implement a L2 pooling layer in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

I am trying to find out if there are any ways to implement an L2 Pooling Layer in Keras. Does anyone have any idea of how to deal with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728873/how-to-implement-l2-norm-pooling-in-keras)

Comment: It seems there are more discussions about L2 norm layer. These are two different things. I am looking for L2 pool Layer.

Answer (score 1):

Building on top of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36620995/how-to-use-l2-pooling-in-tensorflow) answer and the one I mentioned in the comment here is the L2-norm pooling layer you are looking for.

```
from keras.layers import Lambda
import keras.backend as K

def l2_norm2d(x, pool_size = (2,2), strides = None,
             padding = 'valid', data_format=None):
    if strides is None:
        strides = pool_size
    x = x ** 2
    output = K.pool2d(x, pool_size, strides,
                          padding, data_format, pool_mode='avg')
    output  = K.sqrt(output)
    return output
```